# Order through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to order a query through a fairly complicated association and not having luck.

Here are the relevant parts of the models...

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :matches, :through => :participations
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :athlete
  belongs_to :match
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :athletes, :through => :participations
  scope :unplayed,      -> { where("started_at is NULL and year=2015") }
end
```

I need to order a collection of Athletes by "athlete.matches.unplayed.count".  So I have the has_many :through association to deal with as well as the "unplayed" scope on Match.

Adding clarity in response to comment.  Specifically, I have this table in a view:

```
            <% @athletes.each do |athlete| %>
                <% match = athlete.matches.in_progress.first %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= athlete.full_name %></td>
                    <td><%= athlete.idle? ? "Idle" : "Playing" %></td>

                    <% if athlete.idle? %>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    <% else %>
                        <td><%= match.sport_name %></td>
                        <td><%= match.arena_name %></td>
                        <td><%= match.elapsed_time_string %></td>
                    <% end %>
                    <td><%= athlete.matches.unplayed.count %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
```

I'd like the table, and therefore @athletes, ordered by that last column I display "athletes.matches.unplayed.count".

From the controller, @athletes is:

```
@athletes = Athlete.active
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `order` by what ? What is the desired result ?

Comment: I need to order the returned set of athletes by what would be returned in rails by "athlete.matches.unplayed.count".

Comment: cool.. Show the controller action, where you are setting the value of `@athletes` ..

Comment: Did you try `@athletes = Athlete.active.order('coulmn')` ? `column` is the name of the column by which you want to order your result set.

Comment: What's 'column'?  There's no part of the Athlete model that I'm ordering by.  It's a count of a specific scope of matches obtained through the association.  That's the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I create this scope

```
scope :order_by_machets_unplayed, ->
  {joins(:matches).where('matches.started_at is NULL and matches.year=2015').group('athletes.id').order("count(matches.id) desc")}
```

Is not elegant, but works

- *Pros*:
  The database sort yours elements, Not ruby
- *Cons*:

  - Not DRY
  - it is not simple to read

Comment: And this is a scope on the Athlete model?

Comment: I know, is Not DRY :/. 

But i tell you, this is a partial solution. You need create a new field in Athlete to store that count. After that if a match change you can update your count